# How can I get a literal single quote in a git alias (that's a bash function)?

Tags: git, bash

I'm working on a code-base that has a number of different git repos. So, I'm playing with submodules to try and organize all of them into one source repo. It looks something like this:

```
source
  |- ember
  |- rails
```

I'm now trying to make a git alias to checkout the same branch-name in all of the repos. If I do this by hand, the command looks like this on the command line:

```
git checkout -b <branch-name>; git submodule foreach 'git checkout -b <branch-name>'
```

I'd like to be able to just type:

```
git sco -b <branch-name>
```

and have `sco` expand to the full command. So far, I've come up with this:

```
<.gitconfig>
...
[alias]
  sco = "!f() {\
    if [ $# -eq 0 ];then\
      branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);\
      git submodule foreach 'git checkout '"$branch"'';\
    else\
      git checkout $@;\
      git submodule foreach 'git checkout '"$@"'';\
    fi\
    }; f"
```

Notice that if there are no arguments passed to `sco` it will checkout the current branch in all submodules. That case works as expected. It's the case with parameters that isn't working. I think(tm) the reason is that the single quote is being swallowed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `$branch` and `$@` variables will not expand in the single-quoted strings. You also failed to quote` $@` in the `git checkout` command. What part of that alias isn't working correctly?

Comment: @EtanReisner right. Looks like this was a slightly outdated version. I'll edit the example. But, I don't understand why `$branch` and `$@` _are_ inside a single quoted string. The entire alias is a double quoted string and I want the single quotes to be literal single quotes inside that string.

Comment: The outer double quotes are for the git-config quoting. The shell doesn't see them. It only sees the contents of the outer quotes. If the shell did see the outer quotes then the whole thing would just be a string and end with an error when the shell ran it.

Comment: `git submodule foreach` requires the associated command to execute to be provided as a single argument, right?  But when the shell expands `"$@"`, each function argument is expanded to a separate word.  If there's more than one, then your command will be broken up.  You can fix that by changing to `"$*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EtanReisner I figured it out. The key insight was that the single quotes in the alias are interpreted as a single quoted string by bash. Here's the final alias:

```
  sco = "!f() {\
    if [ $# -eq 0 ];then\
      branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);\
      git submodule foreach '"'"git checkout "$branch'"';\
    else\
      git checkout "$@";\
      git submodule foreach '"'"git checkout "$@'"';\
    fi\
    }; f"
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: You need to have `\"$@\"` to not have git's parsing eat your `"` characters